# Performance issue using LoadOnDemand approach in RadComboBox, at external server

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid, radcombobox

There is a `RadGrid` with `RadComboBox` inside it. 
Since I had to bind 20,000+ records in `RadComboBox` so I use `LoadOnDemand` approach to do so. 
Things are working fine at internal server after I host the website. But this `LoadOnDemand` is working very slow at external server for external users. 
They are complaining about bad performance. 
Below are the links that I followed for implementing this approach, these links are working so good but then why there is performance issue at my side?

1. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/comboingrid/defaultcs.aspx?product=combobox
2. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

Please let me know why the behavior of same approach is different at 2 servers : Internal and external. Please help me out in this. 
Please note that I am new to Telerik.

Comment: Could you please check both server are on same network, database server is not same internal/external server, internet speed on both server?

Comment: @JayeshGoyani: Thank you for the reply. Database server is **same** for both internal/external server. Both servers are on same network path as well. Also, Internal server has 32 GB RAM and external server has 16 GB RAM. Please let me know what could be the possible reason of this and how do I solve it. Please reply

Comment: @JayeshGoyani: Please reply to my query.

Comment: There are multiple reason for this issue. 1) Is Telerik licence was expired. 2) Is SQL server taking much time in returning result. 3) Is radDropdown taking much time to bind the data? 4) Sometimes if page is too heavy so it will take much time to updating the element. To check this thing please create one test page and add only radcombobox in test page.  5) Is this browser specific issue?

Comment: @JayeshGoyani: Thank you for the reply. My concern is I am using same Database server for both external and internal servers, and at internal server 2), 3), 4) points are working with delay of few seconds then why delay time exceeds to minutes at external server ? Please let me know. 
5) This is not browser specific issue. 1) Telerik licence is not expired at all.